# transition-delay not working on an element(:before) CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have made an animation in css, it's working fine but I want it to delay or complete its one cycle if mouse is un-hovered from the element see the below snippet. I have tried some solutions from internet as `transition: all 0s ease 1s;` to `:before` element but it's not working at all.

**My code**

```css
.upvote, .downvote {
 position: absolute;
 font-size: 40px;
 transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
}
.upvote:before {
 transition: all 0s ease 1s;
}
.upvote:hover:before {
 transition: all 0s ease 5s;
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
 content: '\f106';
 font-weight: 900;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 color: #28a745;
 animation: upvote 1.3s linear infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes upvote {
 0% {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.5;
 }
 80% {
  transform: translate(0, -30px);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 99% {
  transform: translate(0, -30px);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
.downvote:hover:before {
 font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
 content: '\f107';
 font-weight: 900;
 position: absolute;
 top: 1px;
 color: #dc3545;
 animation: downvote 1.3s linear infinite;
 animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@keyframes downvote {
 0% {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
 }
 50% {
  opacity: 0.5;
 }
 80% {
  transform: translate(0, 30px);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 99% {
  transform: translate(0, 30px);
  opacity: 0;
 }
 100% {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="upvote">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="downvote">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
  </div>
```

Comment: You will have to rely on javascript for this solution. You are asking css to rely on actions that only the DOM can interact with. My recommendation: instead on trying to force the animation to continue on hover out, animate back to the original position.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to be transitioned?

Your ".upvote:before" selector has no properties to transition. Wildcard "all" gave you bad service.
I usually explicitly specify transition property, so it is obvious what will be transformed.

Also pseudo-element ":before" should start with "::", as "::before". Browsers usually forgive minor mistakes, but at some moment you may face some weird behavior.